# Take xml data and append it to a web address

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing, append, converters

I have an xml file which contains data I need to append to a web address.
For example i need to take `<Number>` value from the below xml data and append it to a web address `http://WebAddress.com/?Property="NumberValueGoesHere"`

I'm trying to keep at as simple as possible by using a powershell script.
I can load and parse the data however when I place the object in the web address it shows up as: `http://WebAddress.com/?Property==System.Xml.XmlElement` instead of the number in the xml.

Is this something that is achievable?

My powershell currently reads....

```psh
[Xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -path C:\Data.xml
$Number = $XmlDocument.Ids.Number 
$url = "https://WebbAddress.com/property=$Number"
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)
```

Xml Data File looks like....

```
XML Test
    "< ?xml version="1.0"?>
   -< Link>
-< Ids>
< Number>10609< /Number>
< /Number>
< /Link>
```

Comment: $url = "https://WebbAddress.com/property=$($Number)"

Answer (score 1):

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Link>
    <Ids>
        <Number>10609</Number>
        <Number>00000</Number>
    </Ids>
</Link>
'@

foreach ($num in $xml.Link.Ids.Number)
{
    $url = "https://WebbAddress.com/property=$num"
    Invoke-WebRequest $url 
}
```